# Probability(Bayes rule)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

**10%** *of men* have disability, **8%** *of women* have disability.
***First:*** **Mother** **doesn't** have disability => probability **child will have** disability is 0,05.
***Second:*** **Mother** **has got** disability, **father doesn't have** disability => probability **child will 
                                                           have** disability is 0,3.
***Third:*** **Mother has got** disability, **father has got** disability => probability **child will 
                                                           have** disability is 0,8.
***Question:*** Let's say **parents** have **2 children** and **first child has disability**, about parents I don't know anything(they haven't been tested). What is a probability that **second child** will have also disability? 

P(H1) = 0,92 P(A|H1) = 0,05 for **first.**
 P(H2) = 0,08*0,9= 0,072 P(A|H2) = 0,3 **for second.**
 P(H3) = 0,08*0,1 P(A|H3) = 0,8 **for third.**

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to do the probability of parents don't have disability, but child has disability the result was 0,5595 but i don't have a clue how to do this type of question.

Comment: Surely from writing 'Bayes rule' in the title you understand that this question can be tackled with conditional probability. Try to write out what the information given to you means in symbolic probability notation. Having things laid out like $\Bbb P(A|B)$ can help you understand where to go and how to get to $\Bbb P(B|A)$ using Bayes. The law of total probability also generally helps in these situations.

Comment: P(H1) = 0,92 P(A|H1) = 0,05 for first.
P(H2) = 0,08*0,9= 0,072 P(A|H2) = 0,3 for second.
P(H3) = 0,08*0,1 P(A|H3) = 0,8 for third.

Comment: What $A$, what are the $H_k$? I encourage you to write them down.

Comment: Ok, its edited.

Comment: Let $M$ be the event that the mother has the disability, $F$ the event that the father has it, $C$ the event that the first child has it, and $C'$ the event that the second child has it. You are looking for $$P(C'|C) = P(C'|M^c)P(M^c|C) + P(C'|M\cap F^c)P(M\cap F^c|C) + P(C'|M\cap F)P(M\cap F|C)$$ I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M^*$ be the event of the mother having the disability, $M$ be the event of the mother not having the disability and so on. There are three main possibilities.

$M$ has probability $0.92$.

$M^*\cap F$ has probability $0.072$.

$M^*\cap F^*$ has probability $0.008$.

Probability of event $D$, a child having the disability is:

$0.92\times 0.05+0.08(0.9\times 0.3+0.1\times 0.8)=0.074$.

$p(M|D)=\frac{0.92\times0.05}{0.074}=0.6216$

$p(M^*\cap F|D)=\frac{0.072\times0.3}{0.074}=0.2919$

$p(M^*\cap F^*|D)=\frac{0.008\times0.8}{0.074}=0.0865$

So, the conditional probability of the second child having the disease is

$0.6216\times 0.05+0.2919\times 0.3+.0865\times 0.8=0.1875$.